# In Ruby, can you perform string interpolation on data read from a file?

Tags: ruby, string, interpolation

In Ruby you can reference variables inside strings and they are interpolated at runtime.

For example if you declare a variable `foo` equals `"Ted"` and you declare a string `"Hello, #{foo}"` it interpolates to `"Hello, Ted"`.

I've not been able to figure out how to perform the magic `"#{}"` interpolation on data read from a file.

In pseudo code it might look something like this:

```
interpolated_string = File.new('myfile.txt').read.interpolate
```

But that last `interpolate` method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of interpolating, you could use [`erb`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). [This blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160401113123/http://www.rrn.dk/rubys-erb-templating-system) gives simple example of ERB usage,

```
require 'erb'
name = "Rasmus"
template_string = "My name is <%= name %>"
template = ERB.new template_string
puts template.result # prints "My name is Rasmus"
```

[`Kernel#eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) could be used, too. But most of the time you want to use a simple template system like `erb`.

Comment: Or perhaps using something like liquid would be safer. It's the same concept as erb without the ability for malicious users to damage your application.

Comment: Using eval could pose a huge security risk and is not recommended unless you trust the file contents.

Answer (score 33):

I think this might be the easiest and safest way to do what you want in Ruby 1.9.x (sprintf doesn't support reference by name in 1.8.x): use Kernel.sprintf feature of "reference by name". Example:

```
>> mystring = "There are %{thing1}s and %{thing2}s here."
 => "There are %{thing1}s and %{thing2}s here."

>> vars = {:thing1 => "trees", :thing2 => "houses"}
 => {:thing1=>"trees", :thing2=>"houses"}

>> mystring % vars
 => "There are trees and houses here."
```

Comment: Best answer.  Not as heavy as erb, not as risky as `eval`.

Answer (score 23):

Well, I second stesch's answer of using erb in this situation. But you can use eval like this. If data.txt has contents:

```
he #{foo} he
```

Then you can load and interpolate like this:

```
str = File.read("data.txt")
foo = 3
result = eval("\"" + str + "\"")
```

And `result` will be:

```
"he 3 he"
```

Comment: and as always, be careful with your eval's

Comment: rampion is right. And this is important with every language that has such a feature.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to at least do a first pass of escaping any quotes in `str`, so the eval should be:  `eval('"' + str.gsub(/"/, '\"') + '"')`

Comment: This begs exploitation and is a poor choice, imho. It's like shell escaping—just don't do it yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Ruby Facets provides a [String#interpolate](http://rubyworks.github.io/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.io/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-class-String/api-method-String-d-interpolate) method:

> Interpolate. Provides a means of
>   extenally using Ruby string
>   interpolation mechinism.

```
try = "hello"
str = "\#{try}!!!"
String.interpolate{ str }    #=> "hello!!!"
```

> NOTE: The block neccessary in order to
>   get then binding of the caller.

Comment: Your link is dead. Also this, in ruby 2.0.0 I got an undefined method for method 'interpolate' on class 'String.'

Comment: Agreed - `interpolate` is gone.

Comment: The link seems to be working, by now. The ruby facets `String#interpolate` method appears to be provided in the *facets* gem, not as part of the Ruby core library - also [available at GitHub](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets). There's [source code available for the method itself](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/string/interpolate.rb), with documentation

Comment: I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75920077/553865) that shows how to work with the `interpolate` method from the `Facets` gem.

Answer (score 9):

You can read the file into a string using IO.read(filename), and then use the result as a format string (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25):

myfile.txt:

```
My name is %{firstname} %{lastname} and I am here to talk about %{subject} today.
```

fill_in_name.rb:

```
sentence = IO.read('myfile.txt') % {
  :firstname => 'Joe',
  :lastname => 'Schmoe',
  :subject => 'file interpolation'
}
puts sentence
```

result of running "ruby fill_in_name.rb" at the terminal:

```
My name is Joe Schmoe and I am here to talk about file interpolation today.
```

Answer (score 6):

The 2 most obvious answers have already been given, but if they don't to it for some reason, there's the format operator:

```
>> x = 1
=> 1
>> File.read('temp') % ["#{x}", 'saddle']
=> "The number of horses is 1, where each horse has a saddle\n"
```

where instead of the #{} magic you have the older (but time-tested) %s magic ...

Answer (score 1):

Using [daniel-lucraft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11951/daniel-lucraft)'s answer as my base (as he seems to be the only one that answered the question) I decided to solve this problem in a robust manner.  Below you will find the code for this solution.

```
# encoding: utf-8

class String
  INTERPOLATE_DELIMETER_LIST = [ '"', "'", "\x02", "\x03", "\x7F", '|', '+', '-' ]
  def interpolate(data = {})
    binding = Kernel.binding

    data.each do |k, v|
      binding.local_variable_set(k, v)
    end

    delemeter = nil
    INTERPOLATE_DELIMETER_LIST.each do |k|
      next if self.include? k
      delemeter = k
      break
    end
    raise ArgumentError, "String contains all the reserved characters" unless delemeter
    e = s = delemeter
    string = "%Q#{s}" + self + "#{e}"
    binding.eval string
  end
end

output =
begin
  File.read("data.txt").interpolate(foo: 3)
rescue NameError => error
  puts error
rescue ArgumentError => error
  puts error
end

p output
```

for the input

```
he #{foo} he
```

you get the output

```
 "he 3 he"
```

The input

```
"he #{bad} he\n"
```

will raise a NameError exception.  And the input

```
"\"'\u0002\u0003\u007F|+-"
```

will raise and ArgumentError exception complaining that the input contained all available delimiter characters.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well throw my own solution into the mix.

```
irb(main):001:0> str = '#{13*3} Music'
=> "\#{13*3} Music"
irb(main):002:0> str.gsub(/\#\{(.*?)\}/) { |match| eval($1) }
=> "39 Music"
```

The weakness is that the expression you want to evaluate may have further { } in it, so the regex should probably be improved.

Comment: Great for simple contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @andrewgrimm was on the right track, but incomplete. The [Facets gem](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets) has `String` extensions, including `interpolate`, which is precisely what the original question asked for.

```bash
$ gem install facets
```

Use it almost exactly as the OP requested. Note the `require` statement.

```bash
require 'facets/string/interpolate'

interpolated_string = String.interpolate { File.new('myfile.txt').read }
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
require 'facets/string/interpolate'

string = 'There are #{thing1}s and #{thing2}s here.'
thing1 = 'stick'
thing2 = 'stone'

puts String.interpolate { string }
```

Displays:

```
There are sticks and stones here.
```