# How to store a dynamic URL with variable patterns in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bunch of objects (100s/1000s) stored in a model that have a varying URL pattern that I import variables to.

The URL patterns are different but my variable are still the same:

```
site1 = Site.create {
  name: "Site1", 
  query_format: "http://site1.com?keywords={keywords}&some_other_variable={other_variable}"
}
site2 = Site.create {
  name: "Site2", 
  query_format: "http://site2.com/search?kw={keywords}&var={other_variable}"
}
```

I want to be able to perform an operation such that I can add a method to get the populated string.

site.rb:

```
def construct_query(keywords, other_variable)
  query = self.query_format.gsub("{keywords}", keywords).gsub("{other_variable}", other_variable.to_s)
end
```

and have it output:

```
site1.construct_query("test", 3)
=> "http://site1.com?keywords=test&some_other_variable=3"
```

I want to store these formats against the model so I can dynamically generate the query string.

- Is there a cleverer "rails way" to do that?
- Is there a good way of storing the "dynamic" string? (The above seems a bit "hacky")
- Is there a solid way of making those insertions into the variables that's a bit more reliable than string replacement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Ruby, can you perform string interpolation on data read from a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346380/in-ruby-can-you-perform-string-interpolation-on-data-read-from-a-file)

Comment: Hi, not really a duplicate of that one. That question is about how you insert into strings from a file. Mine is about how you store a 'dynamic' string in the DB. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: Both are same - in both cases, there is a string with place holders where values will be placed at run time.  Its an example of using String interpolation in different way.  It does not matter whether String comes from DB or file.  You can treat your URLs like an ERB template as first answer indicates.   As far as creating those URLs are concerned, I guess you have already figured that part - you have shown a hash of site & URLs

Comment: Ah, my point was that I don't want to do it the way described above... That's riddled with security holes and frankly a hack. It was just an example to illustrate the inputs and outputs of the process. 
The hash above should be a model. I'll correct

Comment: Okay, don't worry - 4 more people need to feel that its a duplicate before the question goes on hold.  If you get any different answer than that thread, it will be new learning for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basis for a template engine in Ruby is String's `gsub`. People regularly miss/ignore this signature:

```
gsub(pattern, hash)
```

and example:

```
'hello'.gsub(/[eo]/, 'e' => 3, 'o' => '*')    #=> "h3ll*"
```

but it's extremely powerful. (Both are in the documentation.) For instance:

```
substitutions = {
  '{keywords}' => 'foo',
  '{other_variable}' => 'bar'
}

substitution_regex = /#{Regexp.new(Regexp.union(substitutions.keys))}/
# => /(?-mix:\{keywords\}|\{other_variable\})/

url = "http://site1.com?keywords={keywords}&some_other_variable={other_variable}"

url.gsub(substitution_regex, substitutions)
# => "http://site1.com?keywords=foo&some_other_variable=bar"
```

However, you're dealing with URLs which introduce some special conditions; There are characters in URLs that are illegal, and there are ways of encoding multiple values that aren't intuitive. When dealing with URLs we need to rely on the StdLib [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) class and/or the [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem, both of which can encode the values according to the RFCs.

I'd start with:

```
require 'uri'

substitutions = {
  'keywords' => 'foo',
  'some_other_variable' => 'bar'
}

url = "http://site1.com?keywords={keywords}&some_other_variable={other_variable}"

uri = URI.parse(url)
params = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h
# => {"keywords"=>"{keywords}", "some_other_variable"=>"{other_variable}"}

uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params.merge(substitutions))
# => "keywords=foo&some_other_variable=bar"

uri # => #<URI::HTTP http://site1.com?keywords=foo&some_other_variable=bar>
```

Now, imagine if `keywords` was actually an array. Trying to substitute that into the URL using a regex and `gsub` would break the URL and would require a lot of additional processing. Instead, using URI makes it much easier:

```
require 'uri'

substitutions = {
  'keywords' => %w[foo bar],
  'some_other_variable' => 'ba&z'
}

url = "http://site1.com?keywords={keywords}&some_other_variable={other_variable}"

uri = URI.parse(url)
params = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h
# => {"keywords"=>"{keywords}", "some_other_variable"=>"{other_variable}"}

uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params.merge(substitutions))
# => "keywords=foo&keywords=bar&some_other_variable=ba%26z"

uri # => #<URI::HTTP http://site1.com?keywords=foo&keywords=bar&some_other_variable=ba%26z>
```

Note that `keywords` is now an array, and `some_other_variable` contains a character that has to be escaped but URI correctly handles them.

Also note that it's not necessary to have the parameters stored with the URL; `query=` assumes all the values are being passed at once so this works:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://site1.com")
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form('foo' => 'bar', baz: 'zed')
uri # => #<URI::HTTP http://site1.com?foo=bar&baz=zed>
```

I used `merge` above so any existing parameters that didn't exist in `substitutions` would continue to be passed:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://site1.com?abc=def")
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h.merge('foo' => 'bar', baz: 'zed'))
uri # => #<URI::HTTP http://site1.com?abc=def&foo=bar&baz=zed>
```

Another example shows that it's not even necessary to have placeholders for the values being replaced, all that's necessary is knowing the parameter names. This maintains `abc` and its associated value while substituting values for `foo` and `bar`:

```
replacements = {'foo' => 'new_foo', 'bar' => 'new_bar'}
uri = URI.parse("http://site1.com?abc=def&foo={p1}&bar={p2}")
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h.merge(replacements))
uri # => #<URI::HTTP http://site1.com?abc=def&foo=new_foo&bar=new_bar>
```

And this shows we don't even need the value placeholders in the templates being stored in the database:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://site1.com?abc=def&foo=&bar=")
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h.merge(replacements))
uri # => #<URI::HTTP http://site1.com?abc=def&foo=new_foo&bar=new_bar>
```

As shown further up, it's not even necessary to have the parameters being replaced as part of the stored template. These would all be equivalent:

```
?abc=def&foo={p1}
?abc=def&foo=
?abc=def&foo
?abc=def
```

because URI's `query=` and `merge` would maintain the existing parameters and overwrite the ones you wanted overwritten. Breaking down what's happening might help you see it:

```
replacements = {'foo' => 'new_foo', 'bar' => 'new_bar'}

uri = URI.parse("http://site1.com?abc=def&foo={p1}&bar={p2}")
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)                                               # => [["abc", "def"], ["foo", "{p1}"], ["bar", "{p2}"]]
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h                                          # => {"abc"=>"def", "foo"=>"{p1}", "bar"=>"{p2}"}
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h.merge(replacements)                      # => {"abc"=>"def", "foo"=>"new_foo", "bar"=>"new_bar"}
URI.encode_www_form(URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h.merge(replacements)) # => "abc=def&foo=new_foo&bar=new_bar"

uri = URI.parse("http://site1.com?abc=def")
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)                                               # => [["abc", "def"]]
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h                                          # => {"abc"=>"def"}
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h.merge(replacements)                      # => {"abc"=>"def", "foo"=>"new_foo", "bar"=>"new_bar"}
URI.encode_www_form(URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h.merge(replacements)) # => "abc=def&foo=new_foo&bar=new_bar"
```

Using URI and an additional hash to map the keywords to/from the various URLs you have and the associated information in your database should solve the problem.

The only other problem is how to map into URLs with disparate parameter names. Meditate on this:

```
require 'uri'

SITES = {
  site1: {'keywords' => :kw1, 'some_other_variable' => :kw2 },
  site2: {'kw'       => :kw1, 'var'                 => :kw2 }
}

substitutions = {
  kw1: 'foo',
  kw2: 'bar'
}

URLs = {
  site1: 'http://site1.com?keywords={keywords}&some_other_variable={other_variable}',
  site2: 'http://site2.com/search?kw={keywords}&var={other_variable}'
}

uri = URI.parse(URLs[:site1])

site_keywords = SITES[:site1]
# => {"keywords"=>:kw1, "some_other_variable"=>:kw2}

site_keywords_keys = site_keywords.keys
# => ["keywords", "some_other_variable"]

site_keywords_values = substitutions.values_at(*site_keywords.values)
# => ["foo", "bar"]

uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(site_keywords_keys.zip(site_keywords_values).to_h)
# => "keywords=foo&some_other_variable=bar"

uri
# => #<URI::HTTP http://site1.com?keywords=foo&some_other_variable=bar>
```

That should give you enough to figure everything out, ever, for dealing with this sort of problem.

Comment: This is great. You've actually solved an issue that I have been struggling with for a while (how to insert an array of values into a query without having array [] symbols stuck into the query values).
The issue (and perhaps it's insurmountable) is that I know the value is "test", I just don't know what this particular site usesas the key for that variable... "keywords" or "kw"...
That's what I want to define in the stored url for each object. Does that make sense?

Comment: You have to have intimate information about the sites' URLs and pick which params you are overwriting. Then create an intermediate table that maps from each site's parameter name to your own internal parameter name. Then you are well on your way to substituting regardless of the parameter names. You only have to have a translation/mapping table you maintain.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite that simple. I'll update the question, but there are lots of completely irrelevant parameters that I want to totally ignore.
e.g. www.site1.com?a=blah&b=albatross&cdefgh=somethingelse&kw={keywords}...etc Where I just want to pluck out that keywords parameter but leave everything else in place.

Comment: When you ask a question it's critical that you provide all the requirements; Adding them as we try to help wastes our time because it can nullify previous work and answers. What you want is not that hard; `merge` is the key if you want to retain some parameters and overwrite others. Based on what you've told me you have everything you need in the examples but you just need to figure out how to put them together.