# Why is rails code embedded in text attribute printing as text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, strong-parameters

I have a model Post with a text attribute Body, and I want to be able to insert images into the text, using HTML tags, so an example Body value would look like this:

```
post.body = "this is text <img src='file.png'/> that was an image"
```

and then `post.body.html_safe` prints as text and an image. But this doesn't work on production, because the file name gets a unique hash during assets precompilation, so the only way to get the file's path is to use `image_url`. But when

```
post.body == "this is text <img src='#{image_url("file.png")}'"
```

the image's path is just literally "#{image_url("file.png")}" in plain text. I'm really confused about this because when I set the `post.body` in the view, it suddenly works, even though it's set to the same value. The only difference is where the value is set.

Here's a demonstration of what I mean:

---

**Scenario 1**

1. A post is created with a click and then edited with a form:

create button:

```
<%= link_to "new post", create_post_path %>
```

edit view:

```
<%= form_for(@post, url: update_post_path(@post)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit "save" %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.create
    redirect_to edit_post_path(@post)
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

2. The saved blog view:

   `<% Post.each do |post| %>
     <%= post.body.html_safe %>
   <% end %>`
3. The picture is missing and this is the text in the source code:

   `<img src='#{image_url("file.png")}' />`

**Scenario 2**

1. Same thing as in Scenario 1
2. The saved blog view:

   " %>
3. Picture prints normally and in the source code the img src is the full path of the file.

---

What's the difference between these two scenarios??? I'm so confused. I feel like it has something to do with Rails security measures when the `post_params` are being used but I have no idea.

Comment: I see no reason why `#{image_url("file.png")}` would not be interpolated, **unless** you've used *single quotation marks* (`'`) instead of *double quotation marks* (`"`) when setting the value.

Comment: Can we see the code in your controller action, as described in scenario 1? That's there the value is being set, and I suspect you're setting it to the wrong thing (i.e. without interpolation).

Comment: `this is text <img src='#{image_url("file.png")}'` is what is stored in the database in the `body` column of the `post` table if I understand correctly?

Comment: @vmarquet You're right, it's actually `<img src='\#{image_url(\"file.png\")}' />`. I'm not sure why those slashes are there but could that be the reason? When I try to remove the slashes it gives me a "undefined method 'image_url'" error.

Comment: @JoeMorano *"I'm not sure why those slashes are there"* -- As I wrote above, I'm almost certain this is because of how you are saving the data. I'll ask again: What code is in the controller, as described in "Scenario 1", where you create/update the `Post`? This is the crux of your question, and you haven't shown us the code.

Comment: @TomLord My apologies, I added the code for my form and the corresponding controller code. The fundamental problem really does seem to be the fact that the slashes are added when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1**

When you do:

```
Post.each do |post|
  post.body.html_safe
end
```

ERB will **not** inspect the `post.body` content to interpret Ruby code. Code into the `#{...}` syntax in a string is only interpreted when you declare a string in ruby code, not when it is present in a string coming from database from example.

Formulated another way, when ERB sees `post.body`, it only understands "output the content of the string", but it will **not** parse the string searching for ruby code inside `#{}`.

The scenario 2 works because it has nothing to do with scenario 1. Scenario 2 isn't about ERB outputting a string. In scenario 2, the line `post.body = "<img src='#{image_url("file.png")}' />"` is interpreted by the Ruby parser, which will search for `#{}` in the string being defined, and will execute the code inside those.

**Wrong solution**

The first solution that comes to mind would be to parse manually the `post.body` content so it interprets Ruby code inside `#{}`, but that would be a huge security vulnerability if some untrusted people edit the posts, as they could write any Ruby code in the post and get it executed.

In the same style, you could use ERB `<%= ... %>` instead of Ruby's `#{ ... }`. Example: `ERB.new("My name is <%= name %>").result`.

**Better solution**

Don't save Ruby code within the `post.body`. You could save only the image filename in the `src`, and before rendering the post, apply some preprocessing to replace the filename with the full path. You will need a Ruby library to parse the post html and find all the `img` tags. One such library is Nokogiri.

Comment: How can I run erb manually on the post.body content? Only admins have access to editing and creating posts, so security isn't an issue.

Comment: Also, do you know how I could save post.body as plain text? Trying to set `post.body = <img src='#{image_url("file.png")}' />` gives a nomethod error.

Comment: @JoeMorano 1. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346380/in-ruby-can-you-perform-string-interpolation-on-data-read-from-a-file 2. If you mean using the `image_url`  helper outside a view, `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url`

Comment: @JoeMorano as a note the general rule of thumb is "NEVER TRUST USER INPUT" this does not mean administrators should be exempt from this rule. How would you feel if a disgruntled admin decided to make the post body `User.delete_all` and you could have avoided this by taking a small amount of additional time to guard against this?